# Is there a way to write a jenkins job that keeps state across runs?

Tags: jenkins

For testing a pipeline with a retry-option I'd like to create a Jenkins job that will pass or fail in some pattern across runs. For example:

```
run 1: failure
run 2: failure
run 3: pass
```

and then repeat the pattern.

I don't want to assume that the job will be using the same workspace or even the same node but I am ok preventing concurrent runs... so just marking a text file won't necessarily work.

I was thinking it could be done via artifacts but am not sure how to set that up... can a job load an artifact from the previous job?

Any suggestions on how I might put something like this together would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... this is what I did in case it's useful for anyone else:

I'm using a 'freestyle' job that *does not* allow concurrent builds.

The job will use a text file named `counter.txt` that just contains a single line with the counter # in it as my 'state'. I'll save that as an artifact at the end of my job and load it at the start.

```
$ cat counter.txt
1
```

First build step: load `counter.txt` from artifacts:

[image]

Second build step: bash script to pull the value and check against a threshold (in my case 3). Exit with status=1 unless counter >= 3.  If `counter.txt` doesn't exist it's created and set to 1, otherwise we load the file and increment it, and check the value to determine if we meet the PASS condition.

[image]

I added two post-build conditions, first I archive `counter.txt` as an artifact and then delete the workspace. I doubt deleting the workspace is necessary but I added it to just make sure the `counter.txt` file I'm getting is the artifact in case Jenkins decided it didn't want to overwrite the file or something.

[image]

When I run this it's doing the right thing:

[image]